# Inputting DEM min value into ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, dem, arcgis-10.5

I am building a model in ArcGIS 10.5 and I need to input the min value of a DEM as one of the variables.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

In ModelBuilder, you could use the model parameters to input the DEM min value.

[Model Parameters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/model-parameters.htm)

> Any model variable can be made a model parameter. There are two primary reasons to make a model variable a parameter.
>
> Output variables that are set as model parameters are added to the map when the model is run inside ModelBuilder.
>
> Variables that are set as model parameters show as tool parameters when the model is run as a geoprocessing tool, allowing you to specify different data or values for your model to process than what was specified when the model was created.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I'm looking for a tool that will automatically input the min DEM value into the model. I am buidlding this model for people who maybe no nothing about rasters, so I want to make this automatic and not input the value manually as in a model parameter

Comment: Ok, I seem to have found what I was looking for with the Get Properties tool (Raster in Data Mangement). I would like to see a solution using the Calculate Value option though, but don't know about the python scripting.